# VCF parser for eventual genomic data visualization

Tags: object-oriented, parsing, node.js, bioinformatics, ecmascript-6

I've just started out writing an [app](https://github.com/emkk/parse-vcf) that will visualize genomic data for anybody to understand.

When you get your genome sequenced the raw data usually comes in the form of a VCF file. I started out by drafting parser below that essentially creates a JavaScript object out of a VCF text file. Next I think want to write a schema-like JSON file (since there doesn't seem to be any database with an API that correlate genotypes to phenotypes based on GWAS) that I can query for phenotypes with the genotypes generated by the parser. For example, if I want to know if a specific genome has the genotype for lactose-intolerance, red hair or alcoholism pre-disposition, I can consult this manually written schema that maps genotypes to phenotypes.

If you have genomics background all the better, but I'm mostly looking for advice concerning my usage of OOP and any other insights. How would you go about the more downstream front-end parts of the app (the actual visualization, was thinking something like a timeline and a ['humonculus'](http://classes.midlandstech.edu/carterp/Courses/bio210/Chap12/210_figure_12_07_labeled.jpg). React? D3?)?

```
(function iife() {

'use strict'

const fs = require('fs');

// Output class for parsing genotype file
class Genome {
  constructor(name) {
      this.name = name
      // Find genotype by rs-ID without having to know chromosome
      this.findByRsId = (rs_id) => {
        for(var chr in this) {
          if (chr.substring(0, 1) === 'c') {
            for(var id in this[chr]) {
              if (id == rs_id) {
                return this[chr][rs_id]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      // Get actual sample's genotype
      this.getSampGenotype = (rs_id) => {
        let rs = this.findByRsId(rs_id)
        switch(rs.fit) {
          case '0/0':
            return rs['genotype'][0]+rs['genotype'][0]
            break
          case '0/1':
            return rs.genotype
            break
          case '1/1':
            return rs['genotype'][1]+rs['genotype'][1]
            break
          case '0':
            return rs.genotype
            break
          case '1':
            return rs.genotype
            break
          default:
            return rs.genotype
            break
        }
      }
      // Get ref genotype
      this.getRefGenotype = (rs_id) => {
        var rs = this.findByRsId(rs_id)
        return rs.genotype
      }
  }

}

// Helpers
var handleRow = (row) => {
  // Parse row into data items
  if (row.length === 10 && row[0] != '#CHROM' && row[2].substring(0,2) === 'rs') {
    // If no chr_[num] exists, make one
    if(!myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]]) {
      myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]] = {}
    } else {
      // If no rs_[num] exists, make one and set it to genotype
      if (!myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]][row[2]]) {
        myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]][row[2]] = {
          'genotype': row[3]+row[4],
          'quality': row[6],
          'fit': row[9]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var handleGFGChunk = (data) => {
  // Cut up chuck into array of rows, then pass to row handler
  var lines = data.split('\n')
  var cols = lines.map((l) => l.split('\t'))
  cols.forEach( (r) => handleRow(r) )
}

var check = (obj) => {
  console.log(obj.findByRsId('rs1556032'))
  console.log(obj.getRefGenotype('rs1556032') === 'CT')
  console.log(obj.getSampGenotype('rs1556032') === 'CC')
}

/*=====================
  Parsing of VCF file
=====================*/

// Have e.g. genotypes class on the ready
var myGenotypes = new Genome('edmund')

// Read VCF
var readFromFile = __dirname + 'vcf/GFG_filtered_unphased_genotypes.vcf'
var GFGfile = fs.createReadStream(readFromFile)
GFGfile.setEncoding('utf8')

// Write Genome upon code
// var writeToFile = 'GFG.js'
// var GFGclass = fs.createWriteStream(writeToFile)

// Start the parsing!
GFGfile.on('data', handleGFGChunk)
GFGfile.on('close', d => console.log('Checked genotype class') )
GFGfile.on('end', d => check(myGenotypes) )

})()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good, but it could be improved:

---

## Nesting

Try and avoid *massive* nesting like this, but reversing the conditions and `continue`ing:

> ```
> class Genome {
>   constructor(name) {
>       this.name = name
>       // Find genotype by rs-ID without having to know chromosome
>       this.findByRsId = (rs_id) => {
>         for(var chr in this) {
>           if (chr.substring(0, 1) === 'c') {
>             for(var id in this[chr]) {
>               if (id == rs_id) {
>                 return this[chr][rs_id]
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
> ```

Into something a little less nested:

```
class Genome {
  constructor(name) {
      this.name = name
      // Find genotype by rs-ID without having to know chromosome
      this.findByRsId = (rs_id) => {
        for(var chr in this) {
          if (chr.substring(0, 1) !== 'c') continue;
          for(var id in this[chr]) {
            if (id != rs_id) continue;
            return this[chr][rs_id]
          }
        }
      }
```

---

### Consistency

This is the only semi-colon you use in your entire script:

> ```
> const fs = require('fs');
> ```

You should keep your consistency in check, and either do or don't use semicolons (I would suggest the former), but keep consistent.

---

### Naming

You're shouldn't be sacrificing readability in your code just to save space.

- `getSampGenotype`: Literally two characters missing to massively improve readability
- `handleGFGChunk`: This could be improved, however I would assume those working your code would know what it means, I, on the other hand, don't.

## What is `rs`??!??

You use the abbreviation/term `rs` everywhere in your code, but to anyone without a doctorate, this might not be clear.

---

### `switch` it to better code:

<sub>Excuse the horrible pun there, but...</sub>

Your switch statement can be simplified:

> ```
>       case '0':
>         return rs.genotype
>         break
>       case '1':
>         return rs.genotype
>         break
>       default:
>         return rs.genotype
>         break
> ```

Here, you're defining multiple cases that have the same result.

There's two ways to approach this problem, while the first is better for readability, it's redundant in this case not to use the second

`switch` statements use *fall throughs*, which means, if you don't explictly declare `break`, it will keep falling down and down.

Take this snippet for example:

```js
document.getElementById("testbutton").addEventListener('click', function(){
    var sample = "ACTA",
        result = "";
    switch(sample){
        case "ACTA":
            result += "A";
        case "AATC":
            result += "B";
        case "UUCA":
            result += "C";
        case "FAIL":
            result += "D";
        default:
            result += "E";
    }
    document.getElementById("content").innerText = result;
});
```

```html
<button width="200" height="200 id="testbutton">Test</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

What do you think would print?

> You would expect that to print `A`, because it's the only case that matches, but because it falls through, it catches all of them and alerts `ABCDE`.

Change `sample` to `UUCA` and watch what happens:

> `CDE` is alerted.

Number 1: So, seeing as content inside a `case` is optional, as shown above, you can "*merge*" cases, like the following:

```
      case '0': case '1': default:
        return rs.genotype
        break
```

However, Number 2: `default` is a *catch-all* of sorts, anything that isn't declared as a `case` above is caught by `default`, so not declaring `case '0'` and `case '1'` is  the same as declaring them in this case.

Depending on how you feel about readability, you could make it look like:

```
      case '0': case '1': default:
        return rs.genotype
        break
```

Which, while redundant, it readably shows that cases `0, 1` have been considered and their result determined.

---

### Indentation:

Your block at the moment, looks like this:

```
(function iife() {

'use strict'
class Genome {
  constructor(name) {
  }
}
})()
```

I see two things wrong with this:

- After your IIFE declaration, there isn't an added indentation
- You're using two-space indentation, when you should be using four-space indentation.

---

### Duplication:

You have a bit of duplication in this code block:

> ```
> if(!myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]]) {
>   myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]] = {}
> } else {
>   // If no rs_[num] exists, make one and set it to genotype
>   if (!myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]][row[2]]) {
>     myGenotypes["chr_"+row[0]][row[2]] = {
>       'genotype': row[3]+row[4],
>       'quality': row[6],
>       'fit': row[9]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

See how many times you needed to call `"chr_" +row[0]`? That's how you know you deserve a variable.

```
var propertyName = "chr_" + row[0]
if(!myGenotypes[propertyName]) {
  myGenotypes[propertyName] = {}
} else {
  // If no rs_[num] exists, make one and set it to genotype
  var subPropertyName = row[2]
  if (!myGenotypes[propertyName][subPropertyName]) {
    myGenotypes[propertyName][subPropertyName] = {
      'genotype': row[3] + row[4],
      'quality': row[6],
      'fit': row[9]
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Magic numbers:

Building on the last point, you call array indexes at `0`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `6`, `9`:

What are these points? What is at `row[0]` that may or may not be in `myGenotypes`?

You ought to move these array indexes to their own variables to declare the importance that each of these indexes holds.

---

### Object and array properties

An object's properties can be accessed in two different ways: `Object.property` or `Object[property]`.

In JavaScript, an array is basically an object where the index position is the key, however you cannot use the first syntax option with arrays.

Normally, you would use the `Object.property` version to visually show that this variable is an Object and not an array,
whereas you would use `Object[property]` when you have to load the property in from a variable, and not specifically by name:

```
var property = "cats";
Object.cats == Object[property];
```

---

### IIFE:

In your IIFE, you give it the name `iife`, however in an IIFE that function name has no meaning, the function itself is discarded in favour of its result, meaning the name is redundant.

---

### Miscellanous:

> ```
>   this.getRefGenotype = (rs_id) => {
>     var rs = this.findByRsId(rs_id)
>     return rs.genotype
>   }
> ```

This can be simplified down to:

```
  this.getRefGenotype = (rs_id) => {
    return this.findByRsId(rs_id).genotype
  }
```

Comment: This was a great informative answer. It has also made me think about how I want to move forward with the app's design. I've included the refactored version in the original post. Cheers and thanks!